# Putting MySQL data into an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli, store

I've tried for a couple of days to get all of the data from a MySQL column and put it inside an array, formatted in the following way:

```
$aSpam= array
    ( '.info'=> 'i'
    , 'anal'=> 'i'
    , 'anus'=> 'i'
    , 'arse'=> 'i'
)
```

I've managed to echo it out formatted properly as you can see here: http://www.yourgrumble.com/phpbbforum/getSpam.php

with the following PHP code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "db";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT `SpamWord` FROM spamWords";
                            $result = $conn->query($sql);

                            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                                // output data of each row
                                $counter = 0;
                                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                    if($counter){
                                        echo ", '" . $row["SpamWord"]. "'=> 'i'";
                                        $counter++;
                                    } else {
                                        echo "'" . $row["SpamWord"]. "'=> 'i'";
                                        $counter++;
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                echo "Error!";
                            }
                            $conn->close();
                        ?>
```

I've read and tried more than 10 solutions found in the web and here at stackoverflow, however none of them worked. I've really got desperate and I cannot get through this without your help guys.

**Edit**
For example I tried with this solution, but it didn't work:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $new_array[$row['id']]['SpamWord'] = $row['SpamWord'];
}

foreach($new_array as $array)
{       
   echo $array['SpamWord'].'<br />';
}
```

Thank you all in advance,
Denis Saidov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like below:-

```
$sql = "SELECT `SpamWord` FROM spamWords";
$result = mysqli_query($conn ,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$resultArray = array(); // create an array
   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                $resultArray[$row["SpamWord"]]  = 'i'; // assing value

        }
    } else {
        echo "Error!";
    }

echo "<pre/>";print_r($resultArray); // print array
    $conn->close();
```

**Note: Here you will get your original array containing all `SpamWord` values comes from database.thanks**

Comment: I've updated my post with your code and what I've received is an empty array. Could you please, take a look. Thank you!

Comment: I did. It is displaying the whole column, I want inside the array. Take a look -> http://i.imgur.com/WSjeYKU.png

Comment: Yeah! It work, but it is displaying them this way -> http://www.yourgrumble.com/phpbbforum/getSpam.php . I need them to display this way: http://i.imgur.com/9Ja6bUp.png

Comment: Just a quick question. I know that with apostrophes work. Is there a difference if it will be an array with: 'content' => 'i' or it will be [content] => 'i' ?

Answer (score 0):

PHP array's are like dictionnaries (a list of key/value pairs)
First, before your loop, create your array empty:

```
$new_array = Array();
while...
```

Then for each column, you append the column value as a new key for the array

```
$new_array[$row['SpamWord']] = "i";
```

As in your example, I put `"i"` as the value for each array's row.